# angular fail using letters ø, æ, å, maybe something about i18n

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm having some problem with my angular.

I can't make it use the letters "æ,ø,å"
I tried installing I18N, but doesn't seems to do anything.
when i navigate to a page url which contains one of the letters, it's convert it to something like this

> Ops%EF%BF%BDtning

And it should be something like

> Opsætning

And the same thing happen when i use it on the pages. like shown here
[image]

I been using angular a long time, but this problem have never happen for me before. can anyone share some wisdom. Im sure it's something stupid little mistake i just can't see my self.

anyway, thanks for your time,

Comment: Is it an option to encode them in the document as `&#248;`, `&#230;`, `&#229;` etc?

Comment: Are your source files UTF encoded? If not then try saving them as UTF-8 by selecting encoding in your editor. That should fix the second problem at least.

Comment: When you use it on the pages, are you fetching the text from the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure to set the right charset, in your case utf-8

```
meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' />
```

- You might have to convert your files to use utf-8 (Notepad++ has a 'Convert to UTF-8' function)
- Alternatively you could use HTML special character codes for: æ ('&aelig';), ø ('&oslash';), å ('&aring';)

You can read more about the use of special characters in HTML, XML and JS [here](http://e-tidsskrift.dk/dev/tegntabel.html)

Comment: The problem was as described that the document was not UTF-8 encode. everything worked after converting this,. thanks